# How to change Background image every x amount of seconds

Tags: html, angular, typescript, setinterval

I'm pretty new to Angular and programming in general.

I wanted to change the background image of my Page by using the `setInterval` method.  It should change every second but for some reason, it changes much faster.

Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  images: Image[] = [];
  changeBackgroundCounter = 0;
  constructor(private imagesService: ImagesService) {}

  getImage() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.changeBackgroundCounter = this.changeBackgroundCounter + 1;
      if (this.changeBackgroundCounter > this.images.length - 1) {
        this.changeBackgroundCounter = 0;
      }
    }, 1000);
    return this.images[this.changeBackgroundCounter].image;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.images = this.imagesService.getImages();
    console.log(this.images[0]);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ getImage() + ')'}" [ngClass]="{imageBackground: getImage()}">
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setinterval?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: getImage is called tons of times so you are creating tons of intervals

Answer (score 3):

You're complicating your code for nothing. Create a variable, equal to a string, and assign it a new value every X seconds in your ngOnInit() !
Then set the background image equals to that variable, and voilà !

Here is what it look like in code :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  images: Image[] = [];
  actualImage: string;
  changeBackgroundCounter = 0;
  constructor(private imagesService: ImagesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.images = this.imagesService.getImages();
    this.actualImage = this.images[0].image;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.changeBackgroundCounter++;
      if (this.changeBackgroundCounter > this.images.length - 1) {
        this.changeBackgroundCounter = 0;
      }
      this.actualImage = this.images[this.changeBackgroundCounter].image;
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

I kept as much as possible of your inital code. My new variable is called `actualImage`, I set a default value in my ngOnInit, right after you get all your images from your service.
Then I call setInterval and set a new value to `actualImage` every 5 seconds !

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setinterval-f5bghq

CARE: When using setInterval, be used to clear it on ngOnDestroy(), it can lead to some weird bugs you don't want to get involved in.
Simply create an other variable, type any, and do the following :

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {...})

ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my problem, it was really helpful! 

Comment: use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) `this.changeBackgroundCounter=(this.changeBackgroundCounter+1)%this.images.length` -this avoid this "ugly if";

Answer (score 2):

In your template, you have

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ getImage() + ')'}" [ngClass]="{imageBackground: getImage()}">
```

This means angular keeps calling the `getImage()` method to find out what the background should be. This will happen very frequently. Each time the method is called, a new interval is created, so there end up being loads of them. You can see this by putting a line of logging within your interval and you will see how often it's being triggered.

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('interval triggered'); // <------- add this line to see how often this code is running
  this.changeBackgroundCounter = this.changeBackgroundCounter + 1;
  if (this.changeBackgroundCounter > this.images.length - 1) {
    this.changeBackgroundCounter = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

To fix your problem, you need to call `getImage()` only once, which can be done within `ngOnInit()`. The template can get the image from `images[this.changeBackgroundCounter].image`.